# 'action' is not defined in reducer - React, Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've got a reducer set up, however the console complains that 'action' is not defined  no-undef

```
import { getName } from '../actions';
let defaultState={
 name: "Sam"
}
const mainReducer=(state = defaultState, simpleAction)=>{
if (action.type === "CHANGE_NAME") {
return{
  ...state,
  name: action.name
}

} else {
return{
  ...state
}
}
}

export default mainReducer
```

Comment: It is `simpleAction`

Comment: it should be `(state = defaultState, action)`

Answer (score 0):

Just change `simpleAction` to `action`

Answer (score 0):

Do it something like this:

```
import { getName } from '../actions';
let defaultState = { name: "Sam" }
const mainReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    if (action.type === "CHANGE_NAME") {
        return { ...state, name: action.name }
    }
    else {
        return { ...state }
    }
}
export default mainReducer
```